# Com faz para instalar o kivy no ambiente anaconda no mac os x10.9?

Tags: python, anaconda

Já tentei instalar conforme a instrução:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Connecting-Kivy-with-Anaconda-(OSX)

Erro:

> (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File
>   "/Users/cicerozanoni/anaconda/envs/kivy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/wi‌​dgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace) File
>   "/Users/cicerozanoni/Documents/Python/Kivy/examples/widgets/label_text_size.py",
>   line 10, in  import kivy ImportError: No module named kivy

Sem sucesso. já tentei trocar o link para dentro do ambiente criado no anaconda e nada...alguém tem alguma dica?

Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia explicar os erros que recebera? Assim alguém pode auxiliá-lo com mais facilidade.

Comment: OLá...a mensagem é de que não reconhece o kivy...mas no python do sistema, reconhece...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cicerozanoni/anaconda/envs/kivy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/cicerozanoni/Documents/Python/Kivy/examples/widgets/label_text_size.py", line 10, in <module>
    import kivy
ImportError: No module named kivy

Comment: Tentou a minha resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Consultando meu anaconda encontrei o kivy para osx-64, como seu link é de 2016, pode ser que o anaconda tenha incluido o pacote e a documentação não registrou não tenho um mac aqui para testar, mas se o pacote estiver integro e for mesmo o kivy, deve funcionar, veja os passos:

**Faça uma busca no anacoda:**

```
$ anaconda search kivy
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     Judowill/kivy             |    1.8.0 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated multitouch applications.
     akode/kivy                |    1.9.1 | conda           | osx-64         
     auto/kivy-garden          |    0.1.1 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : http://kivy-garden.github.io/
     krisvanneste/kivy         |    1.8.0 | conda           | win-64         
     krisvanneste/kivy-garden  |    0.1.2 | conda           | win-64         
     moritzimend/kivy          |      1.9 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : latest development version of kivy
     pypi/Kivy                 |    1.8.0 | pypi            |                
                                          : A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated multitouch applications.
     pypi/kivy-garden          |    0.1.2 | pypi            |                
                                          : Kivys Garden tool to manage extensions for kivy framework.
     wgarcia/kivy              |    1.9.1 | conda           | linux-64       
Found 9 packages
```

**Observe o pacote `akode/kivy`, agora vamos obter informações de como instala-lo:**

```
$ anaconda show akode/kivy
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Name:    kivy
Summary:                                                                                                                                     
Access:  public                                                                                                                              
Package Types:  conda                                                                                                                        
Versions:                                                                                                                                    
   + 1.9.1                                                                                                                                   

To install this package with conda run:                                                                                                      
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/akode kivy
```

**Criando um ambiente para o kivy:**

```
conda create -n kivy python=3.6
```

**Instalando o kivy:**

```
$ source activate kivy
(kivy)~$ conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/akode kivy
```

Instale os outros pacotes, a maioria deles vc pode usar o pip.

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema! O visual code estava usando o python 3.11 e a instalação do Kivy estava no python 3.9

Resolvi da seguinte forma:
Desinstalei o python 3.11 deixei só o python 3.9 instalei o anaconda, criei um ambiente chamado kivy39 com onpython 3.9 como interpretador, depois instalei o kivy no ambiente virtual do anaconda com o seguinte comando: conda install kivy -c conda-forge

Resolvido rodando liso aqui no macos ventura com apple m1

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).